# Why can't I run the file located in the bin?

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, terminal

Need to use the `flare` file and `flasm`, which the chown and permission are correct. Why can run only one and not the other?

```
-rwxr-xr-x  1 daniela.morais sudo    64808 Mar 19 13:54 flare*
-rwxr-xr-x  1 daniela.morais sudo   108525 Mar 19 13:48 flasm*
daniela.morais@tusk:/usr/local/bin$ flare

Flare 0.6 build Jun 11 2007

Copyright (c) 2003-2005 Igor Kogan
All rights reserved. See LICENSE.TXT for terms of use.

Usage: flare filename.swf
Decompiled ActionScript code is stored in filename.flr.
daniela.morais@tusk:/usr/local/bin$ flasm
bash: /usr/local/bin/flasm: No such file or directory
```

Flare: http://www.nowrap.de/flare.html Flasm: http://www.nowrap.de/flasm.html

Comment: What does `file flare flasm` report?

Comment: Do you have SE Linux enabled and some funny permissions?

Comment: What do you get from `head ./flasm` ?  Probably it depends on a script interpreter that isn't found.

Comment: When I try to run inside the folder, displays "bash : ./flasm : No such file or directory". Flare works fine. I have administrator permission.

Comment: What happens if you type "./flasm" from inside the /usr/local/bin folder? What happens if you type "which flasm"?

Comment: wrong ELF interpreter is another possibility. `readelf -l` on the working and non-working program and compare.

Comment: "daniela.morais@tusk:/usr/local/bin$ ./flasm
bash: ./flasm: No such file or directory"

Comment: what is your `$PATH`?

Comment: daniela.morais@tusk:/usr/local/bin$ $PATH
bash: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games: No such file or directory

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley daniela.morais@tusk:/usr/local/bin$ readelf -l flasm

Elf file type is EXEC (Executable file)
Entry point 0x8049150
There are 8 program headers, starting at offset 52
(...)

Comment: I think is because i have 64 bits
daniela.morais@tusk:~/Downloads/config$ file flasm
flasm: ELF 32-bit LSB  executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.2.5, stripped

Idk how I can install in another pc 64 the same "flasm" file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install libc6-i386 lib32stdc++6 lib32gcc1 lib32ncurses5 lib32z1
```

Answer (score 0):

This means flasm is not in the directory you are calling it from, check its location with:

```
find / -name 'flasm'
```

Or with locate and whereis calls

Comment: daniela.morais@tusk:/usr/local/bin$ whereis flasm 
flasm: /usr/local/bin/flasm